# Display Player Coordinates on Simple GUIText

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-gui

Novice here - of course. I'm using Unity 5, and am looking to display on screen the coordinates of a player using a FPS camera. The main reason is I'm using a camera path animator to fly around a terrain scene I built for class, and think by logging coordinates via walking around in FP will make placing my camera path waypoints a lot easier.

What I have done:

-Created new empty game object -Added Component -> Rendering -> GUIText -Added Component -> New Script ->C#

Now I of course searched around to find a solution and found this:

```
 function OnGUI () {
 GUI.Label (Rect (10,120,500,100), "X = " + transform.position.x + " Y= " + transform.position.y + "Z= " + transform.position.z);
 }
```

Which is great! But I am not a strong C# programmer by any means, but I do know this needs a Player variable of some sort yet. So please, could anyone simply direct me, or mind posting the code needed to make player coordinates appear on the screen. This doesn't have to be pretty or anything, I just need to write down the data as I walk around in FP. (unless you want brownie points and know of a way to log coordinates into a .txt file on button press... hahaha Thanks guys!

[image: Where I have script attached]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want....

1. Create new GameObject(GUIText) and make it's parent with your player game object. Now GUIText game object will follow your player object automatically
2. Add new script(i.e, PlayerPositionLogger.cs). to GUIText game object.
3. Find player script on `void Start()` on PlayerPositionLogger.cs or declare `public Player player;` and link player object on editor.
4. Update content of GUIText with player object.

[gist.github.com/growingdever/39b758d5f3967c143744](http://gist.github.com/growingdever/39b758d5f3967c143744)

Comment: Thank you very much for the response - I guess, sadly enough, what I'm looking for is the actual script needed - the PlayerPositionLogger.cs as you stated as unfortunately I am not good with C# at all.

Comment: @theProject try this one https://gist.github.com/growingdever/39b758d5f3967c143744
this script so simple, so you don't need to know csharp very much to understand it.

Comment: Thank you JuHong - unfortunately I'm getting error CS0246 - The type of namespace 'Player' cannot be found Are you missing...  I think this is because I dont have a "true" player?  I'm using a FP Controller camera.  So really I just have basic motor skills with arrow keys and a mouse look c# script.  Should I create an gameobject and try this?

Comment: Ok ok i got what you mean JuHong - the issue is what I should replace "Player" with as its not found in my logic - would that be the name of the parent?

Comment: JuHong I got it working - I needed to rename (from your script_ "Player" with the name I gave my new gameObject - which to fit your script I just nenamed the child gameobject Player - Now I run and play and get over 280 red errors - which teels me its trying to log to coordinates BUT we are getting UnsignedReferenceExceptions as its saying the varaible "player" has not been assigned...am I missing where I assign it?

Comment: JuHong's script worked just fine - I missed linking the new variable player in the editor - thats inexperience for you.  His script outputs the transform coordinates to the console, which is fantastic, thank you very much everyone!

Comment: cheer up! I wish you make fantastic game :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the player object
2. Add component > New Script
3. Add the following code to the script (replace Start and Update)

   ```
   void OnGUI() {
       GUI.Box (Rect (10,10,100,90), "Player position: X:" + transform.position.x + 
       " Y: " + transform.position.y + " Z: " + transform.position.z);
   }
   ```

When you enter playmode it should do what you want. Your main problem was GUI layout.

Comment: Thank you for your help - I selected player object, added a new C# script, pasted your code above in, replacing start and update, but obviously maintaining the proper brackets and I get the following red compiler errors:    CS1503 - cannot convert 'object' expression to type UnityEngine.Rect   CS0119 - expression denotes a type  where a variable value or method group was expected...

Comment: I think the issue here is we need to assign the position to a variable first right? See me not understanding C# doesn't make this easy.  I have basic programming knowledge, just not here.  I would think I should somehow store a variable like "playerPos" - using something like Vector3 from what I'm reading and then display it like you have here... i promise when we get this straight I will write a simple script and post it to the wiki

Comment: @theProject: transform.position gets or sets a Vector3. If that is on the player object, it should be the player's position as a Vector 3.

Comment: Douglas Zare - thanks for the reply and info - I've attached a screenshot in my question showing where I attached the script component per Mingan's directions  - is this wrong?

Comment: What is wrong? Are you getting an error or not the right result?

Comment: @Mingan - yes I was getting a CS1503 - cannot convert 'object' expression to type UnityEngine.Rect CS0119 - expression denotes a type where a variable value or method group was expected.